# WCF service is not updating references (not showing all its types)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a MVC application. I added a Service Reference to it. All good. I was able to see my classes, client, no problem.

I added more classes to my WCF service and there is no way I can make them "show" up in the service reference.

I already tried these steps

- delete the service reference and re-add it. Nothing happened.
- rebuild the whole thing. stop the development server, delete the service, re add it. Nothing happened
- changed the port for development server, (two previous steps). Nothing happened.

At this point I don't know what else to do. I have spent 3 hours on this. I don't know what to google for. all the "solutions" I found, none work for me.

NOTE: When I add, for example, a new property to the existing classes (the ones that actually show up in my client) then I can see them.

ALSO, if a copy one of the classes, exactly as is and change the name only, it DOES NOT show up either.

It looks like WCF only "sees" the classes that were added initially. It ignores anything added recently.

please, help. 
thank you

Never mind guys...

I had added all the new classes but no `OperationContract` was using them. That's why I wasn't able to see them. I added a simple `OperationContract` to my interface, implemented it, and all the types/classes involved in the operation showed up.

Thanks anyway. Sorry for the unnecessary question...

Comment: ??? did you read the whole thing. I pretty much realized what was happening right after i posted the question. then i edited, added this... " Nevermind guys..." and explained i had found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind guys...

I had added all the new classes but no OperationContract was using them. That's why I wasn't able to see them. I added a simple OperationContract to my interface, implemented it, and all the types/classes involved in the operation showed up.

Thanks anyway. Sorry for the unnecessary question...